# Reimplement wm_concat as a user defined aggregate

Tags: oracle, functions, aggregate

We have an application running on Oracle 11 that is using wm_concat. We want to migrate it to Oracle 19. As wm_concat is no longer provided in Oracle 19, we considered rewriting all queries using it, but as it was a lot of work we’re also considering rewriting it as a user defined aggregate.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
create or replace type string_agg_type as object
(
    total clob,

    static function
        ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                             value IN varchar2)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type,
                               returnValue OUT clob,
                               flags IN number)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                           ctx2 IN string_agg_type)
        return number
);
/

create or replace type body string_agg_type is

    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number
        is
    begin
        sctx := string_agg_type(null);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                         value IN varchar2)
        return number
        is
    begin
        self.total := self.total || ',' || value;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type,
                                           returnValue OUT clob,
                                           flags IN number)
        return number
        is
    begin
        returnValue := substr(self.TOTAL, 2);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       ctx2 IN string_agg_type)
        return number
        is
    begin
        self.total := self.total || ctx2.total;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

end;
/

create or replace function wm_concat (input varchar2)
return clob
parallel_enable aggregate using string_agg_type;
/
```

But while it works on small datasets, using it in a query returning millions of rows caused excessive PGA memory usage (over 10GB). It seems it is because CLOB concatenation creates a new CLOB each time and doesn’t free the previous ones (see [High Memory Allocation When Using A Temp CLOB In PLSQL](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2361937_1.html)).

Using a varchar2(4000) instead of CLOB fixes the memory consumption issue, but fails when the output is larger than 4000 characters.

Any idea of a workaround? How can I free the temporary clob generated during the aggregation?

**Edit:**

Yes, I know we shouldn’t have used `wm_concat` in the first place :)
Sadly, now that it is used in different places throughout the code, we have to deal with it.

Replacing those calls with `listagg` was considered, but didn’t work due to its 4000 chars limitation.

This is another attempt using dbms_lob functions. It is performing better but I don’t know where/how to free the CLOBs allocated in ODCIAggregateTerminate:

```
create or replace type string_agg_type as object
(
    total clob,

    static function
        ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                             value IN varchar2)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                               returnValue OUT clob,
                               flags IN number)
        return number,

    member function
        ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                           ctx2 IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number
);
/

create or replace type body string_agg_type is

    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number
        is
    begin
        sctx := string_agg_type(null);
        dbms_lob.createtemporary (
            lob_loc => sctx.total,
            cache => true,
            dur => dbms_lob.call
        );
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                         value IN varchar2)
        return number
        is
    begin
        dbms_lob.writeappend (
            lob_loc => self.total,
            amount => 1,
            buffer => ','
        );
        dbms_lob.writeappend (
            lob_loc => self.total,
            amount => length (value),
            buffer => value
        );
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                           returnValue OUT clob,
                                           flags IN number)
        return number
        is
    begin
        dbms_lob.createtemporary (
            lob_loc => returnValue,
            cache => true,
            dur => dbms_lob.call
        );
        dbms_lob.copy (
            dest_lob => returnValue,
            src_lob => self.total,
            src_offset => 2,
            amount => dbms_lob.getlength (self.total) - 1
        );
        dbms_lob.freetemporary (self.total);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                       ctx2 IN OUT string_agg_type)
        return number
        is
    begin
        dbms_lob.append (self.total, ctx2.total);
        dbms_lob.freetemporary (ctx2.total);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

end;
/

create or replace function wm_concat (input varchar2)
return clob
parallel_enable aggregate using string_agg_type;
/
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the time you are spending on this would be better spent actually remediating your code in the way oracle suggested when they dropped wm_concat.

Comment: Have a look at [how to fix wm_concat in oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56834433/1820861) over on stackoverflow. Might be a solution. Oracle writes: _From Oracle 12.1.0.1 onwards WM_CONCAT function is disabled. We need to use LISTAGG Function._ [Link](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2622063_1.html) (requires login for solution)

Comment: I thought `wm_concat` was undocumented.  What is wrong with the document solution `listagg`? Ps - never use "undocumented features".

Comment: Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212899/convert-wm-concat-to-listagg ?

Comment: I would advise you to use dbms_lob's functions instead of varchar2 concatenation and substring.  It may avoid converting to and from varchar2.  Try to locate when a temporary lob would be created, see if you can create it yourself so that you have a handle you can free.  See if adding nocopy to certain parameters is beneficial.  The solution "you came up with" can be found all over the web, but I doubt it's fit for use with LOBs.  "Ask Tom" used to be invaluable for such problems.